# Why hasn't anybody done a two-telescope test on the speed of starlight?

Tags: cosmology, redshift

It seems that even though it wouldn't be too hard, nobody has taken the trouble to use a pair of telescopes to confirm that light originating from red-shifted / distant stars is indeed traveling at *c*.

I imagine the experiment being pretty simple to set up: identify some predictable astronomical event or oscillation.  Point two telescopes at it, sufficiently separated to allow a good measurement of the time light would take to travel from one to the next, *in the direction toward the object*.

Synchronize the two telescopes, measure the time it took for the event's photons to pass between the two telescopes, and confirm that red-shifted light travels at *c*.  Done!

Comment: Is there reason to believe that they don't know the speed of the starlight?

Comment: Have you considered that c is highly variable and that light is not traveling at a constant velocity?

Comment: This was done in 1676 when the timing of eclipses of Jupiter's moon Io were measured at different points in the Earth's orbit to [determine the speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%B8mer%27s_determination_of_the_speed_of_light)

Comment: @ThePhoton, not for red-shifted light, though.

Comment: "measure the time it took for the event's photons to pass between the two telescopes" -  If the first telescope detects a photon, that particular photon no longer exists. If the second telescope detects a photon, the first telescope did not, so no-one knows when it passed the first telescope. Your proposed experiment is impossible.

Comment: @alephzero he doesn't mean to detect the same photon. He means observing the same event, at different times. This would tell us how long light takes to travel between the two telescopes.

Answer (score 4):

The light travel time across the Earth is about 0.04 s. In order for an astronomical object to vary on such timescales requires the emission to arise from a region that is no bigger than the Earth. But if the emitting object/region is that small then it isn't going to be detectable at distances where there is a significant redshift.

A possible source you might think of is a supernova, but although the energy is generated in a compact region, the light observed on Earth comes from a much bigger region in an expanding fireball and is not "sharp" enough to do the test you propose.

Another possibility is gamma ray bursts. These arise in compact regions - exploding collapsars or merging neutron stars and the signatures (especially for the latter) are reasonably short and sharp. Counterparts can sometimes be identified in their hosting high redshift galaxies. The [interplanetary network](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/InterPlanetary_Network) is a set of gamma ray detecting satellites at various locations in the solar system. It uses the timing differences between satellite detections of gamma ray bursts to pinpoint their location.

The IPN of course assumes that the speed of light is $c$. If it were not then I would think inconsistencies would have arisen both between the timings of the various satellites and the locations of any visible counterparts and I am checking to see what work has been done on that.

An indirect method is to note that the gamma ray burst associated with the kilonova gravitational wave source GW170817, arrived within 2s of the gravitational wave, after travelling 130 million light years. The possible *difference* in electromagnetic Vs gravitational wave speeds is less than about 1 part in $10^{15}$. Any mechanism that "delayed" the gamma rays (aka "tired light") would surely not delay the ultra weakly interacting gravitational waves.

Answer (score 3):

> I imagine the experiment being pretty simple to set up: identify some
>   predictable astronomical event or oscillation. Point two telescopes at
>   it, sufficiently separated to allow a good measurement of the time
>   light would take to travel from one to the next, in the direction
>   toward the object.

This is precisely how they measured the speed of light. Well, sort of. Instead of having two telescopes, they used one telescope that moved between two positions and then observed the event when it happened a second time.

The moons of Jupiter have *very* well known orbits, and using this data you can predict when one of them will disappear behind Jupiter and then do it again the next time. So (for simplicity's sake), let's say the moon disappears at 8 pm tonight, you know it will do so again at 8 pm tomorrow.

But Jupiter moves, as does the Earth, so over the period of months the distance between Jupiter and Earth changes. And when it does, that perfect timing is upset. When Jupiter is further away, the moon doesn't disappear at 8 pm, but 8:01, and so we know it took 1 minute longer for the light to get here. We know how big the orbits are, so now we know the speed of light.

This is how [Ole Roemer measured the speed of light in 1676](https://www.amnh.org/learn-teach/curriculum-collections/cosmic-horizons/profile-ole-roemer-and-the-speed-of-light).

It's really quite brilliant. If you read the original sources and use only the measurements that he rates as good ones, the value you get is within a few percent of the modern value.

In more modern times, this difference in timing is how most radio telescopes are used. Instead of making one huge telescope, you make two smaller ones and separate them, then connect them together using some sort of high-speed link like a microwave relay or fibre optic. Perhaps you've seen the Very Large Array in the US that's a bunch of dishes on railway tracks? You see it in ads and the movie Contact.

Radio waves *travel* at the speed of light, but the *oscillate* much slower than visible light - we measure the waveforms in MHz and GHz - that's fast, but slower than your computer for instance. So what you do is send the signal from one dish to the other and compare them. Since you're both pointed at the same object you know the overall signal is the same. You also know how long it takes for the signal to get from one station to the other. So that lets you move the signals back and forth until they line up.

Now when you do this, there's a little tiny bit of difference left over. And that's because the object you're looking at is not a point source, but spread out, maybe over many light years. By examining the way the signals line up you can extract this information back out and gain mucho resolution. This is known as ["very long baseline interferometry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very-long-baseline_interferometry).

The very first success at this was [just up the road from me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algonquin_Radio_Observatory). They didn't have a direct connection (it was the 60's) so they recorded it to 2" videotape along with the signal from an atomic clock on another channel, and then used that clock signal to line everything up again months later. Nowadays this technique is commonplace, but so much easier through modern telecoms.

Comment: This is also essentially the way the direction of arrival of a gravitational wave is determined: by the relative timing of gravitational wave signals received at detectors at different locations on the globe.

Comment: GW detection and VLBI *assumes* that the waves are traveling at $c$. Whilst there is no reason to doubt it, neither offers any answer to the question posed.

Comment: They only work if c is c, so they are indirectly proving this with every measurement.

Comment: The relative timing of a GW in 2 detectors for a source with *known position* might offer a test. But the precision is many orders of magnitude below that to *determine* a precise speed for the GWs. In contrast, gamma ray bursts can. As I describe.

Comment: Not at all. The technique would work perfectly if the waves were travelling at 0.999c.

Answer (score 0):

A practical way to determine if radiation from a red shifted object arrives more slowly would be by observing 2 objects side by side near the horizon, one red shifted, with a very large array radio telescope and see if the delay to correlate the signal from the closest dishes to the furthest ones needs to be longer for the red shifted one. I would like to speak to an engineer at one of these telescopes because I really want to know aswell.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is, synchronizing the two telescopes. How would you suggest we do this? If they are together when synchronized, time dilation occurs when you move them apart.

Secondly, the type of event you're talking about is a supernovae. Aligning the telescopes in the direction facing the star, requires prior knowledge that the supernova is going to occur.